# What is wrong with this matrix multiplication in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

In the below code (Jupiter notebook), output is given wrong, how to correct the code?

```
import numpy as np

A = [1,22,231,1540]

B = [[-1,1,0],[1,-1,1],[0,6,0],[0,6,0]]

C = [[113401201],[10649],[1]]

result = np.dot(np.dot(A, B),C)

print(result)
```

output

```
 [-1800609408]
```

The actual answer is

[image]

I want to find the error and correct it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably running this code on 32-bit platform (where integers are 32 bit):

```py
A = np.array(A, dtype=np.int32)
B = np.array(B, dtype=np.int32)
C = np.array(C, dtype=np.int32)

result = np.dot(np.dot(A, B), C)

print(result)
```

Prints (incorrectly, because the value overflows):

```
[-1800609408]
```

---

To correct it, use 64-bit values:

```py
A = np.array(A, dtype=np.int64)
B = np.array(B, dtype=np.int64)
C = np.array(C, dtype=np.int64)

result = np.dot(np.dot(A, B), C)

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[2494357888]
```